# jquery slide show plugin like this

Tags: javascript, jquery

please see that site:
[link](http://www.top-pcb.com/)
and watch the slideshow.

How can I create a slideshow like that with jQuery? (is there plugin?)

thanks ..

Comment: Did you put `jQuery slideshow` into a search engine? There are a number of sites with different examples, e.g. http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/top-20-jquery-slideshow-and-image-gallery-tutorials/

Comment: yes, but i didn't find an example like that

Answer (score 0):

This is the best of the ones i have used http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/